# Extract/Convert WMF with C#

Tags: c#, windows, metafile

I have a bunch of binary files with what appear to be embedded Windows Meta Files:

{\pict\wmetafile8\picw9031\pich827\picwgoal5119\pi chgoal468
010009000003F901000005001C0000000000050000000B0200 000000050000000C023B03472303
0000001E00030000001E00050000000C02D501001405000000 0B020000000008000000FA020000
0000000000000000040000002D0100001C000000FB0238FF00 0000000000900100000001070000
00417269616C00F47740000000440E0A440786F5771086F577 0100000000003000040000002D01
010005000000020101000000050000000102FFFFFF00050000 002E011800000005000000090200
blah blah blah
}

Is there a way to convert what I am looking at back into an image with C#?